# Does AllowedFileTypes in UploadDialog allow for multiple file types, and if so, what is the format?

Tags: acumatica

If I just set one file type, it'll filter properly and allow for the image to be uploaded.

If I try multiple file types in the property, it may filter them, but it will always error (screen shots below). I've tried inputting the two types I want as "png, jpg", "png jpg", "pngjpg", and ".png, .jpg", but none of them work. Some of the formats will auto set the filter to show both *.png, *.jpg, but when I select the file I get an error. Can this work with multiple file types?

Setting field values:

[image]

Showing images:

[image]

Error on selecting image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try semi-colon `;` separator?

This is the standard Windows extension separator and there's indication Acumatica uses this character for parsing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets string representing file types which are allowed for selecting.
/// </summary>
[Category("Behavior")]
[Description("The string that lists the file types that are allowed for selecting.")]
public string AllowedFileTypes
{
    get
    {
        return this.allowedFileTypes;
    }
    set
    {
        this.allowedFileTypes = "";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return;
        this.SetAllowedFileTypes(value.Split(';'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not try Semicolon separator. I keep forgetting that that's commonly used to separate things as well. That was it, thanks HB!